# Feof error in C

Tags: c, linked-list, feof

```
struct node 
{
char item[200];
struct node* next;
};

FILE* unionMethod(char f1name[50], char f2name[50])
{
    FILE* f1;
    FILE* f2;

    f1=fopen(f1name,"r");
    f2=fopen(f2name,"r");
    char line[200];
    struct node *head1=NULL;
    struct node *head2=NULL;

    while(!feof(f1))
    {
        fgets(line, 200, f1);
        struct node *cur=head1->next;
        if(head1==NULL)
        {
            head1 = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node));
            fgets(line,200,f1);
            strcpy(head1->item, line);
            head1->next=NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            cur = (struct node *) malloc( sizeof(struct node));
            fgets(line,200,f1);
            strcpy(cur->item, line);
            cur->next=NULL;
        }
    }

    fclose(f1);
}
int main()
{
    unionMethod("inputfile1.txt","inputfile2.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

what I am basically trying to do is getting lines from a file and put them into a linked list. However when execution reaches while part program stops, because of "feof" function. I could not understand the problem with this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong

Answer (score 0):

This is a very frequent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong), just change

```
while (!feof(f1))
```

to

```
while (fgets(line, 200, f1))
```

the reason is that the `EOF` marker is set after `fgets()` attempts to read past the end of the file, so you will need one extra iteration for it to be set.